# Loop lines in UITextView

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview

How can I loop lines in UITextView, I've tried this:

```
//Loop Lines
NSArray *myLines = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (int i = 0; i < myLines.count;i++) {
    NSLog(@"Line[%i] = %@",i,[myLines objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

this will depend on the new line "\n"
but what if the line is very long?? there won't be a \n in it but it will extend to the next line.

Comment: What do you want to do with that code? Maybe we can give you better idea

Comment: I'm trying to do an app like notes and I'm struggling with NSMutableParagraphStyle to set the max/min Line Height, it never gives me the result I need with the arabic and chinese letters, so I need to loop each line and check if it contains these letters

Comment: What do new lines have to do with line height?

Comment: in my case it does a lot !! like I mentioned I have a problem with chinese and arabic letters, lets say I have 3 lines of english letters now if the user edit the second line and inserted an arabic letter it will push down the third line and any line below it.